# how to making token after 30 minutes with php

Tags: php, token

I have a function for making token but when refresh page Function creates a new string I want to create a string after 30 minutes with this function .

```
function token($length=6){
    $character = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomstring = "";
    $num_valid_chars = strlen($character);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);
        $random_char = $character[$random_pick-1];
        $randomstring .= $random_char;
    }
    return $randomstring;
}
```

Comment: You want the same token to be generated for 30 mins?...

Comment: Use a cookie or session variable.

Comment: suppose now is token random string is `FHfdoe` After 30 minutes should be `WtdC5k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store token in **cookie** which expire after **30 minutes**. You can check if **cookie** has value then take it from cookie otherwise create new token.

```
<?php
function token($length=6){
    $cookie_name = "token_set";
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] != "") {
        $randomstring = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
    else
    {
        $character = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomstring = "";
        $num_valid_chars = strlen($character);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);
            $random_char = $character[$random_pick-1];
            $randomstring .= $random_char;
        }   

        setcookie($cookie_name, $randomstring, time() + (1800), '/');   //set for 30 mins
    }


    return $randomstring;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this function working properly There's just one problem when i refresh page after 20 minutes The cookie expiration time will be 10 minutes. i want when refresh page cookie expiration time Start over 30 minutes